# Blackberry: Adding a contact with fields filled in by app

Tags: blackberry, contacts

I have implemented an ActiveRichTextField to my app, which allows user to select a phone number and choose "Add Contact" to add it inside the user's phonebook. However, when it is directed to the phonebook 'add a contact' page, the only field which is filled in is the phone number. I wonder whether it is possible to include fields which are filled like the Name and the phone number, plus the email? Extracting it from my website.

Answer (score 1):

Below, there is code to add name "John Doe" to address book.

```
ContactList contactList = 
            (ContactList)PIM.getInstance().
                              openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.WRITE_ONLY);

    if (contactList.isSupportedField(Contact.NAME)) {
       String[] name = new String[contactList.stringArraySize(Contact.NAME)]; 

       name[Contact.NAME_GIVEN] =  "John";
       name[Contact.NAME_FAMILY] = "Doe";

       contact.addStringArray(Contact.NAME, Contact.ATTR_NONE, name);
    }
```

Use this approach to add email (use Contact.EMAIL) [and other fields](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/pim/Contact.html).